# to retrieve total record id if datetime is greater than current date using query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve total record id if datetime is smaller than current date using myquery for each month.But I cann't retrieve it.I don't get any output .Date structure is datetime like that '2016-2-17 23:20:22'.So,how can I do that?

```
 SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('regist_timestamp','%Y-%m-%d') AS date, count(id) as numberOfVisits from  ash_members
where DATE_FORMAT('regist_timestamp','%Y-%m-%d')<=curdate()
```

Comment: why not just `where date(regist_timestamp) <= curdate()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your count result. If you want monthly grouped result, you can do it this way.

```
SELECT MONTH(regist_timestamp) AS Month, YEAR(regist_timestamp) AS Year, count(id) AS numberOfVisits
FROM ash_members
WHERE DATE(regist_timestamp) < CURDATE()
GROUP BY MONTH(regist_timestamp), YEAR(regist_timestamp)
```